# Getting a anchor tag value in side an unorder list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the value of anchor link which is inside a unordered list and displaying it to the text box. this the current HTML code i have.

```
              <div id="map-navigation" class="map-navigation" style="padding-top:50px;">
                      <div class="dropdown" >
                                      <button style ="border-radius:5px; width:100%; padding:5px;" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Button1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Select a Marine Area
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                      </button>
                                         <ul id="marinelist" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" runat="server">
                                                <li "><a href="#" data-zoom="5" data-position="52.42922, -18.5154" value="Orginal map"> Orginal map.....</a></li>
                                                <li ><a  href="#" data-zoom="5" data-position="56.425, -21.85"> Irish Continental Shelf</a></li>
                                                <li ><a href="#" data-zoom="6" data-position="53.40, -9.0"> Irish Exclusive Economic Zone</a></li>
                                                <li ><a href="#" data-zoom="6" data-position="53.40, -10.0"> Irish Territorial Sea</a></li>
                                                <li ><a href="#" data-zoom="6" data-position="53.40, -9.0"> Irish Contiguous Zone</a></li>
                                                <li ><a href="#" data-zoom="10" data-position="53.212, -9.179" > Galway Bay</a></li>
                                                <li ><a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="53.44, -6.08"> Dundalk</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                                       <input id="bayarea" runat="server" type="text" readonly style="border:0px"/>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
        script type="text/javascript">        onload = function () {
        var sel= document.getElementsById('marinelist')[0];
        var inp = document.getElementsById('bayarea')[0];
        sel.onchange = function () {
            inp.value = sel.value;
        }
    }</script>
```

Currently the javascript does not work and nothing appears in the textbox. This question could have been asked already, Could you help point me in the right direction if so. Thanks

Comment: Your javascript doesn't makes sense. First of all, it's `getElementById`. Second, you can't access the elements as an array. Third where does the `sel` identifier come from, and what do you expect it to be? Try looking at the console for errors, and use `console.log` to output data to the log so you can see what each object is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getElementsById` but the correct syntax is `getElementById`. This is singular because id's should be unique.

To get all the list items you could use `document.querySelectorAll('#marinelist li');` which will return a nodelist.

The following will get the `li` elements as a nodelist then convert them to an array which you can use to access each item with the standard array syntax: `elems[2]`. This is not cross browser compatible however.

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#marinelist li'));
```

If it is just a single item you are trying to get the value of, you can use the singular `querySelector()` which will return the single element which you can then call `.value` on.

Comment: o yes i checked it but made now difference

Comment: You need to either use classes, `getElementsByClassName` or use `querySelectorAll` to return multiple elements. If it is jsut a single element then use css selectors using `querySelector`